# Javascript crashes on special characters from query string

Tags: javascript, typescript

To use this value in my `TypeScript` I am getting it from my query string like this:

```
var UserName = @Request.QueryString["UserName"];
```

But I get a `Unexpeted Identifier error` on it because if in `DevTool` if I go to where it breaks that query string has a value like this:

**var UserName = ANT -- ANT 37690 / THIRD PARTY**

So is there a way to do some kind of sanitation on it so it wouldn't crash? I guess there are illegal characters in that value for `JS`?

Comment: are you string-building JS from razor?

Comment: `var UserName = @Request.QueryString["UserName"];` <- what programming language is that?

Comment: @zerkms - It is the razor engine.

Comment: Why people are down voting my question?!!!

Comment: @Bohn - More than likely because you didn't clarify the server side technology being paired here and they were confused.

Comment: @Bohn - the error has nothing to do with "special" characters, but with the fact that the right side of the assignment - unwrapped in quotes - contains what js engine views as unknown identifiers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to include quotes for the value.

```
var UserName = "@(Request.QueryString["UserName"])";
```

Otherwise the name will come through verbatim in your code and cause the problems you are seeing.

There is no need to protect against an attack vector here as the user can alter the page as they see fit at any time with a user script, and the QueryString is entered by them and only seen as a result by them in this scenario.

If there was a need to scrub the user input, it should be done prior to it actually reaching the view on server side. However, if still concerned about scrubbing output into a view in this type of scenario in general, it would be prudent to include an encode from razor's library.

```
var sanitizedJsVariable = "@System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(model.VariableFromServer)";
```

Comment: It totally is an XSS.

Comment: bad idea, this will fail if the query string includes a properly escaped quote. Use JavaScript serialization of some sort to avoid issues.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162372/discussion-on-answer-by-travis-j-javascript-crashes-on-special-characters-from-q).

Answer (score 3):

The error has nothing to do with "special" characters, but with the fact that the right side of the assignment - unwrapped in quotes - contains what js engine views as unknown identifier[s].

One way to properly format data that becomes part of javascript code is to use `JavaScriptSerializer` class from `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace.

```
var UserName = @new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Seria‌​lize(Request.Query‌​St‌​ring["UserName"]);
```

The shorter version of this for a string is:

```
var UserName = "@System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Request.Query‌​St‌​ring["UserName"])";
```

or overloaded version that wraps the result in double quotes:

```
var UserName = @System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Request.Query‌​St‌​ring["UserName"], true);
```

Comment: Amusingly, this will still produce the exact same error as the OP's code does. However, it certainly attempts to solve the straw man you all came up with.

Comment: @TravisJ I share your amusement.

Comment: There is no point in doing this, it is a huge waste of time and effort. The QueryString is *composed* by the user themselves, and as a result does not represent an attack vector. There is no need to scrub their input, if they want to break, fix, or change the page in any way they can always alter the element structure by editing it or by using a userscript. This may make sense to do from a broad sense, but that wasn't the question being asked nor the situation at hand.

Comment: @TravisJ you seriously need to learn what XSS is before you post anything else here.

Comment: @zerkms - You seem to think userscripting is an XSS vulnerability. You seriously need to re-examine the way you interact with other people over your own misunderstandings.

Comment: @TravisJ userscripting has nothing to do with that code: in the code a value from the query parameter is injected on the page. If not encoded properly - it's a potential XSS. HTML encoding is not a proper encoding for JS.

Comment: @TravisJ - seeing how you edited your answer, I find it strange that you insist that `JavaScriptStringEncode`  is unnecessary. Encodings for strings in javascript and in html are different. There is a number of characters that can be present in server-side string, but will break javascript if all that is done is wrapping them in double quotes.

Comment: @TravisJ P.S. `HttpUtility` has little to do with razor library.

Comment: @zerkms - It is directly from the same user displayed on their own page. It may as well be a userscript. It in this case is more than likely plain text 99.9% of the time except when some user attempts to mess with the page, in which case, they could use userscript it anyway.

Comment: @TravisJ given it's a query parameter - it may be provided by a malicious party as well, not from the user themselves.